# After installing Ubuntu, it shows Error: 0x80070422

Tags: system-installation

After I installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS in my PC, it shows --

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070422
Error: 0x80070422 The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Press any key to continue...
```

I'm not sure what I should do as pressing any key does nothing but closes the terminal.
P.S: I'm using Windows10

Comment: Might want to read through https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3386

Comment: Note that is a Windows error code.  Read through the link that Terrance has put in your comments.